# How to add filter on products ASC and DESC by name (already have filter BY ID)

Tags: php, html, ajax, sorting

I was trying some possible solutions, but it didn't work. Because the SELECT has an ONCHANGE and I don't know how to ADD the name sorting code to add up on my sorting on ID.

**Sorting from newest to oldest BY ID (DATE), I don't know how to do it with sortByNameAsc and Desc**

```
  <select id="sortBy" onchange="searchFilter();">
  <option value="">Date: Newest First</option>
  <option value="asc">Date: Oldest First</option>
  <option id="sortByNameASC" value="asc">Ascending by name</option>
  <option id="sortByNameDESC"value="desc">Descending by name</option>
</select>
```

**Trying to make it work with adding the variables**

```
function searchFilter(page_num) {
  page_num = page_num?page_num:0;
  var keywords = $('#keywords').val();
  var sortBy = $('#sortBy').val();
    var sortByNameASC = $('#sortByNameASC').val();
    var sortByNameDESC = $('#sortByNameDESC').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'getData.php',
    data:'page='+page_num+'&keywords='+keywords+'&sortBy='+sortBy+'&sortByNameASC='+sortByNameASC+'&sortByNameDESC='+sortByNameDESC,
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    success: function (html) {
      $('#postContent').html(html);
    }
  });
}
```

**getData.php**, So I want to add 'ORDER BY name ASC and DESC, I tried also to add the elements here below but it didn't work.

```
  if(!empty($_POST['sortBy'])){
        $orderSQL = " ORDER BY id ".$_POST['sortBy'];
    }else{
        $orderSQL = " ORDER BY id DESC";
    }
$query = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM products $orderSQL");
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using explode:

```
    $result = $_POST['sortBy'];
      $result_explode = explode('|', $result);
      echo $orderSQL = " ORDER BY ".$result_explode[0]." ".$result_explode[1];
```

First result explode is "name" or can be ID. Second result explode is ASC or DESC.